# how to access base url in twig from symfony 2 console?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am porting my website which is in Kohana to Symfony 2 gradually. Right now I am writing backend command in Symfony2, e.g. cron to send email notifications.

How can I access base url in twig. Can I do some configuration so that accessing urls in twig from console and from http request to be same ?

I have already reffered to this,

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html

here, it is given how to configure it, but it is not mentioned how to access it, I assume I have to use {{ router.request_context.host }}.

But my question is, isn't there any way to be consistent between console and HTTP ?

e.g. {{ url }}  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me.

In config.yml:

```
twig:
   globals:
       base_url: "http://www.example.com/"
```

In twig template:

```
{{ base_url }}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add following setting in parameters.yml,

```
router.request_context.scheme: http
router.request_context.host: domain.com
base_url: '%router.request_context.scheme%://%router.request_context.host%/'
```

and inside console command controller you can access like,

```
$host =  $this->getContainer()->get('router')->getContext()->getHost();
$scheme =  $this->getContainer()->get('router')->getContext()->getScheme();
$baseURL = $this->getContainer()->getParameter('base_url');
```

Comment: Hemant, The problem was how to access it in Twig template, not how to access in Controller. Anyways, this is Vishal Melmatti's profile, I have already fixed and committed the same in git 3-4 days before. :)

Answer (score 3):

First, you must set the url (you're calling it base_url) in a route by adding the following lines to /app/config/routing.yml:

```
base_url:
    pattern:  /
```

After that, you must set the router.request_context parameters as mentioned in the Symfony cookbook.

Now that everything's setup, you can simply use the same url functions in Twig as you would do in your webpages:

```
{{ url('base_url') }}
```

Comment: As I have only backend commands in symfony 2 right now and dont have front end (which is in kohana now), can I use url() without argument to get base url ?

Comment: I updated my answer to add your "base_url" as a route. You call it base url, I call it the homepage! :-)

Comment: I dont have home page in symfony2, I have only symfony console commands. My website is in kohana.

Comment: You can create a route without actually having a controller/action linked to it. Just add the base_url route as provided in my example, it'll work.

Comment: Thats great, will try it.